# Firebreath plugin not loading in IE 10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, firebreath

**EDIT:** See end of post for more information.

I am trying to to get plugins created via the Firebreath framework (1.7.0) to load.  I am on Windows 8 in Desktop Mode using Internet Explorer 10.  I've reproduced this with the built-in test FBTtestPlugin that comes with Firebreath.  The failure is silent in that the object element is created, but fails to have any properties specified by the plugin.  How does one go about debugging this? The Microsoft Internet Explorer Compatibility Tool reports that the plugin is failing to load.
[image: MSIECTT]
(The FBTtestPlugin loads three plugins, hence the three errors.)

I've got other (non-FB) plugins working on the same settings (e.g. the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565667(v=vs.85).aspx works fine as do all the examples from this site http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/browser/activexfiltering/Default.html ).

I've tried a huge combination of security settings, but here's the most relaxed set I have so far follows:

- Tools / Safety / ActiveX Filtering: is unchecked
  [image: ActiveX Filtering is Off]
- Internet Options / Security / Internet: "Enable Protected Mode" is unchecked
- Internet Options / Security / Internet: is at Custom Level. Under ActiveX everything is "enabled" except restrictive properties such as "Allow ActiveX Filtering"
- All sorts of security warnings are visible based on these settings.
  [image: Security Settings]

Note: I don't intend to keep these settings.  I just want to get the plugin working, then work backwards re-enabling security settings.

**UPDATE**
I figured this out partly and can now run the FB test FBTestPlugin.  To make debugging easier for IE, I defined the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth as 0 to limit the browser to use one process.  Unfortunately, with IE10 both iexplore.exe in Program Files and Program Files (x86) direct to the 64-bit version of IE.  This prevents 32-bit plugins from running (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716529 ), and the symptom is silent failure.

However, my plugin still fails to load in IE and the retitled question above is otherwise still open.  The problem is still silent load failure.  However, I think it may have something to do with plugin configuration.  The CLSID listed in the Compatibility Test Tool (like the example shown above) is listed as all 0's instead of a valid GUID.  Moreover the registry looks funky: The key HKCR\Company.Name exists as does HKCR\Company.Name.1, but both are empty (instead of having a CLSID child as in normally working plugins).  The expected GUID does exist, but under a bogus name "applications.'".  I am now digging into the code that gets called when regsvr32 is run.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am providing this answer in the hopes that someone can use the result.

IE was not loading the plugin for two reasons.
1) The TabProcGrowth registry key and the 32/64 bit issue with IE 10. ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716529 )
Don't define this key.

2) My plugin description used an apostrophe (e.g. "Gluttco's Plugin") and this messed up the registration of the component.

DETAILS ON 2):
I traced through the DllRegisterServer code and found that the phoney registry entries are due to the fact that my plugin description contained an apostrophe.  E.g. "Joe's plugin".  The generator (fbgen.py/cmake), generated a malformed FBControls.rgs file (it't didn't escape the quotes and thus contained a string literal such as (s 'Joe's cool plugin').  The DllRegisterServer code (called from regsvr32) used the contents of this file (embedded?) when (deep in atlbase.h).  Oddly, the parser did not detect the error (or somehow erroneously recovered).  From Process Monitor I could see a bunch of bogus keys being added, before it started adding good registry keys again.

For now Firebreath plugin descriptions should not contain apostrophes (probably other characters are illegal too).  It might be sensible to make fbgen.py check for these characters and possibly escape, reject, or replace them.

Comment: Mark it as the answer to the question

Comment: Created pull request to fix (2): https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/pull/114

Comment: And the fix was merged to master in https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/commit/10eda67f1e986584feadde2606881d0f340c4cd1 - thanks, taxilian!

Answer (score 4):

Searching found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565667(v=vs.85).aspx

Do you have any group policies in place that could affect it? I don't think this is related directly to FireBreath, rather to the activex configuration...

I also found http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/90c3202c-448b-42b7-acf7-dab8dba7b000/one-or-more-activex-controls-could-not-be-displayed-because-either which has a few things you could try.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this here and on IRC earlier. Firebreath is pretty awesome!

Comment: ... saying thanks and not +1ing the answer for being helpful is a bit empty... =]