# Firebreath Plugin not loading in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, internet-explorer-11, windows-7-x64, firebreath

I have created a 32-bit plugin using Firebreath framework 1.7.0, and I am trying to run the plugin on a Windows 7 64-bit machine running IE 11. When I launch the web-page containing the plugin object, IE prompts for permission to allow the plugin to run. Even though I allow the plugin to run, it does not get loaded in the page and fails silently.

I did see a similar question posted here - [Firebreath plugin not loading in IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304860/firebreath-plugin-not-loading-in-ie-10) - and I have already tried the steps mentioned in this post, but unfortunately it didn't help.

In addition to above I have tried the following, which also unfortunately did not seem to help..

1. Changed the value of *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth* registry entry to 1, 5 - for the 32-bit plugin
2. Built and deployed a 64-bit version of the plugin
3. Used *Microsoft Internet explorer compatibility test tool* to check if the plugin is being loaded for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The plugin failed to load for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions
4. I also changed the security settings for IE to have the least security

I am confident that there is no bug in the plugin code, because the plugin works on a bunch of machines, including mine. However when I deploy the plugin on a customer machine it DOES NOT work.

> **Update 1:**
>   I used depends.exe to verify that there are no missing dependencies on the machine on which the plugin is not working. I did not find any missing dependencies. See attached screenshots for 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Also, when I use *Microsoft Internet explorer compatibility test tool* It clearly says that the plugin is being blocked.

**32-bit Dependency Check:**

[image: 32-bit Dependency Check]]

**64-bit Dependency Check:**

[image: 64-bit Dependency Check]]

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin works on your systems but not on a customer system then I'd say 90% probability that it depends on some library that isn't installed on the customer system; for example it might depend on a runtime or other DLL that it can't find on the system but is installed as part of your dev tools, thus it works for you and not for them.

use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on a machine where it doesn't work to trace missing dependencies.

Comment: I tried what you asked, missing dependency doesn't seem to be the issue. Please see **Update 1**

Comment: In your screenshots... all of those files listed that say "Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)." . Those are missing dependencies.